# Email notifications layout

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there an option to preserve the 2-columns layout of the form in an email notification (when "include entry details is checked")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Currently email notifications and confirmations present entry details in a one column layout with left-aligned field labels.  The reason for this relates to the current state of HTML support in email clients, which do not support many of the modern layout options.  Also, our goal was to have these emails be easy to read on mobile devices, where the majority of email messages are now read each day.

Having said this, I will add this suggestion to our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/b/ZS1698De) and mention it to our design team to get their input and consideration for updates in the future.

Also, for email confirmations, you can create a fully customized email message including entry data like the following example:

[image]